# Writing from file to file program

Tags: java, file, loops

I'm trying to make a program that reads a line from the database.txt and writes an odd/even numbered lines to files 1.txt and 2.txt. F.e. 1st(odd) line of the database.txt goes to 1.txt and the 2nd(even) line of the database.txt goes goes to 2.txt

Here's the code I got so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public Main(){
        op(null);
    }

    public void op(String args[]){
        try{
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("database.txt");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String line = reader.readLine();
            Scanner scan = null;
            int ln = 1;
            String even = "2txt";
            String odd = "1.txt";
            while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
                scan = new Scanner(line);
                if(ln%2==0){
                    wtf(even, line);
                }else{
                    wtf(odd, line);
                }
                ln++;
                line=reader.readLine();
            }
            reader.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("File not found");
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Impossibru to read");
        }
    }

    public void wtf(String filename, String ltw){
        try
        {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(filename);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String line = reader.readLine();

            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filename);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(writer);
            while(line==null){
                bw.write(ltw);
                bw.newLine();
            }
            bw.close();
        }
        catch ( IOException e)
        {
        }
    }
    }
```

At the moment its on an infinite loop reads only the 2nd line and spams it to 1.txt

Comment: I see one problem... You have this line: `String line = reader.readLine();` which reads the first line from text, then this line: `while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null){` which reads the second line. This will completely skip the first line. Also, wouldn't the filename be `2.txt`?

Comment: Your endless loop is in the line `while(line==null)`

Comment: Change code of the form `catch (Exception e) { ..` to `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); // very informative! ..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the wtf method. Your endless loop was in there when you wrote:

```
while(line==null){
                bw.write(ltw);
                bw.newLine();
}
```

BufferedReader states it `returns null if the end of the stream has been reached.`  Since your files are initially empty (I'm assuming), this will constantly be true, and you will continue writing new lines and your String.

I was playing around with your code and rewrote it to something like this.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class fread {
  public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String even = "2.txt";
    String odd = "1.txt";
    String line = "";

    int lineNumber = 0;

    while (scan.hasNext() )
    {
      line = scan.nextLine();
      if (lineNumber++ % 2 == 1)
        writeText(even, line);
      else
        writeText(odd, line);
    }
  }
  static void writeText(String filename, String ltw)
  {
    try
    {
      BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename, true));
      bw.write(ltw);
      bw.newLine();
      bw.close();
    }
    catch ( IOException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

It uses input redirection, so typing `java fread < database.txt` will give you your results, however this only does appends to a file. If your files do not exist, or are initially empty, this will work as you expect. You'll have to specify this code to the needs of the program. Regardless, you should be able to take my writeText method and incorporate it into your program to be able to to get yours working.

Comment: Well it truly does the work but have a small problem implementing the reader. Can I use a code that will immediately process "java fread < database.txt" without the need to type it into the console?

Comment: @VitalijKornijenko You should stick to your FileReader. I just use Scanner because I find input redirection easy to work with. You should be able to pull all of the `database.txt` file input from your code to make this work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've managed to implement the code and it's working great. Marking your answer as THE answer. Thanks again @SaviorSelf :)

Answer (score 3):

Within the:

```
if(ln%2==0)
```

block you also need to add `ln++;`

Also move the

```
line=reader.readLine();
```

to directly outside the else block.

As an alternative, this is a somewhat reworked method:

Remove all of the `line=reader.readLine();`s including the first.

Rewrite the loop as:

```
while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null){

        if(ln%2==0){
            wtf(even, line);
        }else{
            wtf(odd, line);

        }
        ln++;
}
```

Comment: Oddly enough, I think we're both right here.. Two infinite loops. One function. An achievement in it's own right.

Answer (score 2):

You are not incrementing the line count.

```
  while (line!=null){
                scan = new Scanner(line);
                if(ln%2==0){
                    wtf(even, line);
                    ln++;
                }else{
                    wtf(odd, line);
                    ln++;
                    line=reader.readLine();
                }
            }
            reader.close();
        }
```

Comment: Yes, sorry about: 
   if(ln%2==0){
                   wtf(even, line);

it was initially with 
                ln++;
                line=reader.readLine();

But now I have another problem. It now spams the 2nd line to 1.txt

Answer (score 2):

```
      if(ln%2==0){
            wtf(even, line);
        }else{
            wtf(odd, line);
             } //<------------here ?
            ln++;
            line=reader.readLine();
    // }
    }
    reader.close();
```

**update:**

```
   while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
               *
               *
               *
            line=reader.readLine() ; //is this line  required ?
```

**update:**

Check this also in wtf()

```
 while(line==null){
                bw.write(ltw);
                bw.newLine();
        }
```

Comment: Tried swapping ln++ multiple times didn't really help, same result.

Comment: I need this line to jump into the next line and read it. I have a hunch that it's not the correct code. >.<

Answer (score 1):

Your infinite loop is happening here:

```
if(ln%2==0)
    wtf(even, line);
```

`ln` starts at 0. `0 % X = 0`, therefore it is always considered an `even` number, and you just keep `spamming` out to the same line. Add the increment to your even clause.

**Interesting side note**

You have another infinite loop, because if the value is even, or 0, then you never read the next line.

**Solution**

```
if(ln%2==0){
    wtf(even, line);
    ln ++;
    line = reader.readline();
```

Comment: I tried changing int ln to from 1 to 0 and 2. On 0 it didn't even started on 2 it carried on like with 2 so I think the problem is not with ln and  sorry about: if(ln%2==0){ wtf(even, line); it was initially with ln++; line=reader.readLine(); But now I have another problem. It now spams the 2nd line to 1.txt

Comment: I didn't think it was you :) I was just wondering why someone would.